# Bitcoin Payment Processing

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, json-rpc

I'm currently attempting to create a website where Bitcoin Core is used as a payment processor.

I initially planned on making the user input a xpub, but after seeing issues like gap limit on Exodus, I decided to instead have a proxy wallet which would redirect to the wallet that the user specifies.

Every time a user is created a bitcoin wallet is also created with a name that uniquely identifies that user.

I currently have 4 main questions,

1: What is the realistic maximum wallets I can have, I understand that Bitcoin core does not have any specific limit and that the limit is dependent on RAM, but what is a realistic limit for a 2GB RAM VPS, I've seen another post saying they had 100k/1m wallets, I'd only like to hold around 10k-100k, Is that feasible with 2GB of RAM? I also see "unloadwallet"

2: Address rotation, I'd like to preferably rotate between addresses, since I assume this will decrease fees, since the payout has to be sent at the end of the day, its preferable to have less addresses sending to an address means less fees? How would I accomplish this? It seems getnewaddress generates a different address every time, should I simply store such addresses in a database and only generate a new one if all are being used right now? or is there a better way to do it within Bitcoin Core?

3: listreceivedbyaddress, Since I'll be rotating addresses, how would I be able to tell the date of a transaction, to ensure that the date is > invoice_creation_date?

4: I am currently using pruned mode, on 7GB, Will this cause any issues? cause certain transactions to be forgotten somehow?

I'd appreciate any help, Thanks. <3